# Improve Speed of Sub-Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has been getting slower as time goes on.  At first to navigate between records took no time at all.  After awhile it took a second.  Then awhile later it took two seconds when switching records.  Now I am at three seconds when switching records.

***Here are the details:***

The user gets prompted with a form that has some options to choose from.  Based on those options the main form pops up showing only related records.  The main form links to a query that was generated by the users selections.  On the main form is sub form that links directly to another table (QuoteRunResults).  The table right now contains 354,000 records.  ***The form that is slow is the sub form***.

Here is a sample query that may be used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM QUOTERun
WHERE QuoteNumber = {UserSelectedQN}
ORDER BY RunID DESC
```

Is there anyway I can speed up the sub form?

Comment: You have compacted and repaired the back-end database, the front-end database, decompiled the front-end and made sure you have proper indexes, yesno?

Comment: Yes, I have already done all of that.  That is regular maintenance that is being done weekly to keep everything running smooth.  Could it be that the sub form is working with two much data?  Does the form go back to the table that has 354,000 records every time it changes records?

Comment: If it has to get new records, yes it goes back to the table, but if the form can take advantage of indexes it should be quite fast.

Comment: The Child Fields and Master Fields that link the sub form to the main form are indexed.  The main form runs great.  The sub form does not.

Comment: What happens when you open the subform as a form? Or open the query that the subform is based on as a query?

Comment: The sub form is not based on a query.  It is linked directly to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this type of situation before.  What I did to completely remove the lag was the following:

- Use a query to generate the two data sets needed for both forms.
- Programically create a temporary table for each data set and populate it from
  the results of the query
- Link the forms to the temporary tables
- Allow the user to do whatever they need to do to the data
- Once the form is closed programically update the real data from the
  temporary tables
- Delete the temporary tables

This actually made the forms fly. I had no more problems with lag.  When I clicked on the button to move to the next record it happened immediately.  In my situation I had a lot going on in the On Current event that slowed the form down.  Once I applied the above it sped right up.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting copy 300K records across to the user's desktop? If the required selection is less than that the problem can be fixed with a query using well defined indexes, anyway.

Comment: No I was suggesting running the query to get the records the user needs to work with.  Then copy those records into a temporary table to work with.  Indexes helped in my situation but not as much as my suggestion.

Comment: I did try your suggestion and it really increased the speed drastically.  I was actually quite surprised.  I did have to figure out how to lock the records while it was being worked with and update it after the form was closed.  I did figure it out and everything is running great now.